# Firebase server side token invalidation

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying server side to invalidate a registration token forcing the client app to request a new token.

Reading the docs:

> The InstanceID is long lived, but may expire for the following reasons:
>
> Device factory reset.
>
> User uninstalls the app.
>
> User performs “Clear Data” in the app.
>
> Device unused for an extended period (device and region determines the timespan).
>
> Instance ID service detects abuse or errors and resets the InstanceID.
>
> Server-side code if your client app requires that functionality.

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/

Whats the *server side code* that allows me to invalidate or force the expiration of the token ?

Thanks.

---

For example, using the google API:
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/token?details=true

When doing a 'get' over that endpoint I get information of the token. When was created, in what platform is running, and what are the topics registered for that token.

I would like through the API make that token invalid.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Be aware that you are looking at the old Instance ID documentation. I assume you really want FirebaseInstanceId in the firebase.iid package: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId
To invalidate a registration token your server could return a status value to the client indicating that a token is invalid, forcing the client to delete the old token.

Comment: Yes, is documentation from gcm but I wasn't able to find the FCM IID API. Only sdk methods. Doing that means that I have to handle all the logic of deregistration of topics for that token, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. For starters, an Instance ID itself is separate from the token for the Instance ID. The token is a security token, while the Instance ID is just an ID to uniquely identify your app instance for use by GCM, etc. The token can be invalidated separately from invalidating the ID. Could you edit your question?

Comment: I add more description to my question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! I don't know if the API that you want exists. I'd look into the client route for invalidating the token.

Comment: Ok, so there is no server side code to achieve what I ask. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing that I can see, but maybe someone else has an idea. The Instance ID documentation has other errors, it's not the greatest. You could try tracking down a Google Developer Advocate or posting on a Google forum. Maybe try a Firebase forum, those seem to be monitored.